# Probability of drawing a better card on the second go?

Tags: probability

I've been working on a game and calculating the probabilities. I will add the instructions below, but one of the probabilities I don't fully understand is how to calculate what it would be in the case of dealing cards or a card and the probability that one would draw a better card than in hand from the remainder of the deck. I just want to understand the logic and how to work it out, so I can apply it on the much larger scale necessary.

```
- Instructions:
1. Shuffle and Cut deck
2. Dealer gives everyone playing 2 cards
3. Players have 3 options:
- Drop cards --> lose round but get 2 points
- Stay --> Given 1 more cards where they can add anyone of to the original 2 for final hand
- Discard a Card --> Give up a card for more to be dealt around the table starting with player. Opponents can swap one of the cards with one of their original 2. Player must use one of original 2 cards but can add 2 drawn or 1 drawn with the 2 originals in hand. 
4. Game continues clockwise with Dealer getting the last turn
5. Once all players have had turn, cards are show and points tallied 
6. The dealer becomes the person who last went first. 
7. Players play until everyone has been the dealer
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How would I calculate the probability in this situation:                                                      If I draw one card from the deck. What is the probability that my next selection will be a card with a higher value.

Comment: Are the values $1$ to $13$, or are the cards ranked $1$ to $52$ in some way?

Comment: The values are still 1 to 13

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly...

I believe we are assuming that we have two cards in our hands and want to know the probability that if we are dealt another card we will receive a card that is greater than the lower of our two cards. Well, if there are $n$ ranks above your lowest card then there are $4n-1$ or $4n$ cards that are higher than your lowest card(depending on if your two cards are the same or not). There are 50 unknown cards, so the probability is $\frac{4n-1}{50}$ or $\frac{2n}{25}$ depending on if you have a pair or not.